# How to make Fancybox 1.3.4 fit to screen with my Wordpress theme?

Tags: fancybox, themes

Fancybox 1.3.4 JS came with my Wordpress theme, Gridlocked. Everything works properly, but the lightbox popup is too big for the screen. I'd like the image to shrink if needed to always fit on screen.

Looking at the Fancybox site instructions, it seems I want to set "autoscale:true" to fix this, either in PHP or in the JS file itself. The javascript file that came with the theme already has this set to true, but it's not working. I don't know where in all the theme php files I should try to include the argument. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's difficult to say where is the problem without actually seeing anything. Maybe it will be better if you share a link with us, so we can find out where is the problem.

Comment: http://portfolio.brickwilson.com is my site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization of fancybox is done in **jquery.custom.js**.
You can find following lines there:

```
function tz_fancybox() {
    if(jQuery().fancybox) {
        jQuery("a.lightbox").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
            'transitionOut' :   'fade',
            'speedIn'       :   300, 
            'speedOut'      :   300, 
            'overlayShow'   :   true,
            'autoScale'     :   false,
            'titleShow'     :   false,
            'margin'        :   10,
        });
    }
}

tz_fancybox();
```

Change to:

```
function tz_fancybox() {
    if(jQuery().fancybox) {
        jQuery("a.lightbox").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
            'transitionOut' :   'fade',
            'speedIn'       :   300, 
            'speedOut'      :   300, 
            'overlayShow'   :   true,
            'autoScale'     :   true,
            'titleShow'     :   false,
            'margin'        :   10,
        });
    }
}

tz_fancybox();
```